# What does ''we are all there is'' mean?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning, word-choice, word-request

[image]

What is the meaning of this sentence?
There is both "are" and "is" in the sentence.

Comment: Please **transcribe** what you cannot copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

It properly means "We are all that exists".

"All there is" is idiomatic for "all that exists", basically.

"There is nothing apart from us."

Comment: Similar to, but not identical to, "We are all that remain."

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

We are the only ones on this planet. So we are the only ones that can make a difference. There is no one else. The solution is only in our hands.

The author tries to show that we must take this responsibility which no one else but us can carry.

Comment: Thank you very much